# Can wordpress search bar display only files instead of posts?

Tags: wordpress, file, pdf, web, searchbar

I want to upload pdf files to my wordpress page and have my visitors search on the search bar for them, is there a way that they can type on the search bar and the search bar to display my pdf files(and only my pdf files form the media library) instead of showing posts/pages?
I've been researching but can't find anything.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: There's at least a plugin appearing in Google Search that seems to do what you need. Try doing a little research before asking questions here (I don't mean to sound rude but this site is for asking programming questions - and your question has 0 code in it). See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Probably better asked at [wordpress.se].